# Woocommerce - Empty product list on homepage

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to set my `shop` page as a homepage for site. It's an easy action in wp-admin. The problem that I am getting message `No products were found matching your request.`

At the same time everything OK on shopPage. 
I've tried to play with visibility, categories, attributes but still can't customize them properly. I believe, there should be some settings I've missed.

Homepage set to `shop` page -  http://52.58.27.104/

Usual shop page - http://52.58.27.104/shop

Edit

Setting->Reading
[image]

WooCommerce->Settings->Products
[image]

Settings->Permalinks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually to change the page that shows as default you should login to the admin panel then go to Settings -> Reading -> Static Page and from there pick your site. If that's the way you did it then that will remove the extension off your page like the www.site.com/shop will be www.site.com which now means woocomerce is trying to find a /shop section. You have to change the woocomerce section to select the new page that the items are located. Either one by one or through the woocomerce general settings.

Hope that helps

Comment: attached few screenshots with my current settings. Woocommerce knows how to get products on /shop page, but don't on /. So, yes, probably should be something with permalinks.

Comment: any other ideas?@VibraniumData